# Multipanel table titles

Tags: tables

I´m trying to make a table with two panels. I need something like this:

[image]

But I have this:

[image]

I am having problems with the numbers in the titles and their positions, I would also like to remove those [t]. This is my code:

```
\\\begin{table}[!hbt]
  \centering
      \caption{Panel A: Descriptive statistics}
  \begin{subtable}[t]{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \vspace{0pt}
    \begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} l|ccc}
      \toprule
     Observations & 594\\
     Mean & 0.00313\\
     Median & 0.00453\\
     Maximum & 0.22762\\
     Minimun & -0.18917\\
     Std. Dev. & 0.04886\\
     Skewness & -0.10910 \\
     Kurtosis & 2.22092\\
      \bottomrule

    \end{tabular}
        \caption{Panel A: Unit root tests}
  \end{subtable}
  \begin{subtable}[t]{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} l|ccc}
      \toprule
      ADF & -7.7912*** \\
      PP & -604.93***  \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}

    \caption{Descriptive statistics and unit root tests}  
  \end{subtable}
\end{table}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Coud you please add the documentclass and the relevant packages to your code in order to create a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)? With the information you provided one can unfortunately not recreate the output you show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the desired output by using the `subcaption` package as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[subtable]{labelformat=simple, labelsep=colon}
\renewcommand{\thesubtable}{Panel~\Alph{subtable}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!hbt]
  \centering
  \begin{subtable}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \caption{Unit root tests}
    \begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} lc}
      \toprule
     Observations & 594\\
     Mean & 0.00313\\
     Median & 0.00453\\
     Maximum & 0.22762\\
     Minimun & -0.18917\\
     Std. Dev. & 0.04886\\
     Skewness & -0.10910 \\
     Kurtosis & 2.22092\\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{subtable}
 \vspace{0.75\baselineskip}

  \begin{subtable}{\linewidth}
  \caption{Unit root tests}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} lc}
      \toprule
      ADF & -7.7912*** \\
      PP & -604.93***  \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{subtable}
  \caption{Descriptive statistics and unit root tests}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Additionall, I have removed superfluous columns (the table originally had four while only two are needed) as well as the vertical lines (which are incompatible with `booktabs`' horizontal lines).

---

For some further improvement, you might be interested in using the `siunitx` package's `S` type column in order to align the numbers with respect to the decimal separator:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[subtable]{labelformat=simple, labelsep=colon}
\renewcommand{\thesubtable}{Panel~\Alph{subtable}}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!hbt]
  \centering
    \caption{Descriptive statistics and unit root tests}
  \begin{subtable}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \caption{Unit root tests}
    \begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} lS[table-format=3.5]}
      \toprule
     Observations & 594\\
     Mean & 0.00313\\
     Median & 0.00453\\
     Maximum & 0.22762\\
     Minimun & -0.18917\\
     Std. Dev. & 0.04886\\
     Skewness & -0.10910 \\
     Kurtosis & 2.22092\\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{subtable}
 \vspace{0.75\baselineskip}

  \begin{subtable}{\linewidth}
  \sisetup{
  table-format          = -3.4,
  table-space-text-post = ***,
  table-align-text-post = false
}
  \caption{Unit root tests}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} lS}
      \toprule
      ADF & -7.7912*** \\
      PP & -604.93***  \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{subtable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks leandriis! That´s exactly what I need, really helpful.